# Exceeding maximum capacitive load of isolated DC/DC converter

Tags: capacitor, dc-dc-converter, current-limiting

I have never needed to exceed the capacitive load limit of a DC/DC converter before, but I need to for an upcoming application that demands a very low power supply impedance. I believe this is a rather soft limit, because not much background is provided in datasheets, such as [this part](https://www.cui.com/product/resource/pdqe20-d.pdf) or similar parts from other vendors.

- What is the failure mode when exceeding the specced maximum capacitive load of an isolated DC/DC converter?
- Is it acceptable to place more capacitance if there is both an inrush current limiter and a filter choke between the capacitance and the converter?

### Some background:

The power rails are for analog circuitry in a device that is to be mass produced and need an impedance of max. \$5m\Omega\$ at 10 kHz. Impedance at lower frequency can be correspondingly higher due to higher PSRR of the analog circuitry at lower frequency. The easiest way to achieve this, is with about 3 mF capacitance in Al polymer caps. The caps would be anyway preceded by a filter choke of around 22 uH.

While I could just try, I would like to understand the failure mode of DC converters with capacitive overload. That way I can judge better if field application or EMC considerations speak against this use case, even if it works on the bench.

Comment: Is it a one-off or mass production? Best case would be to have CC/CV limit on the power supply, then you could have near infinite output capacitance. If not, it's probably a peak current or thermal limitation for how much and how long you can (over)load it during startup. If one-off, I would just try it, cycle it many times with 2x your planned capacitance and see if anything bad happens.

Comment: Probably the short-circuit protection kicks in and the converter never manages to start. If you are unlucky it only fails to start at temperature extremes or input voltage conditions that are intermittent.

Comment: If you can set your power supply output a little bit higher, cheat and use an opamp with transistor buffer on the output to create a “virtual” rail?

Comment: @winny I had that idea, but mohms at 10kHz impedance even with a regulator/buffer was a bit challenging. so I went for 'just throw el. caps' approach for now. But I will check again, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have contacted CUI about this and they have provided a helpful answer: The output overcurrent protection will get in the way leading to hiccup operation. Therefore, this is foremost a startup problem. They also used the term "recommended output load capacitance" as opposed to "maximum capacitive load" in the datasheet, which confirms that this is indeed a rather soft maximum spec.

Limiting inrush current is an adequate countermeasure.

Even without inrush current limiting, so I was told, the output would eventually reach the nominal voltage and run normally *if* (obviously) the current supplied in hiccup operation is larger than the requested load current.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet does not say what happens, but in general, it then takes longer than expected to charge the excessively large capacitors.

The switch mode power supply feedback can have stability issues due to excess capacitance or simply hitting current limit trying to charge the caps and shut down, perhaps retrying forever.

Comment: That is what I assume aswell. In that case a current limiter and ~10uH filter choke should remove the issue, no ?

Comment: The datasheet does not give enough information to answer that.

Comment: As stated in this answer, a larger capacitance will result in a longer startup, but the other side of this is also "short-circuit protection" as a larger cap will draw higher  current for longer and if there is any protection it could result in a hiccup.  A PI filter (correctly damped) should resolve this